# Using pandas.Grouper to split datetime.time column into time ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am reading from an Excel file that has a column with times. Since I can't upload the actual file, I created the variable `timeIntervals` to illustrate.

When I run this code...

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pyPython import *

def main():
    timeIntervals = pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min").time
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Times": timeIntervals})
    grp = pd.Grouper(key="Times", freq="3H")
    value = df.groupby(grp).count()
    print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

How can I use `pandas.Grouper` in combination with `DataFrame.groupby` to "group" dataframe `df` into discrete time ranges (3 hours) ? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Do `df['Times'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Times'])` before grouping. Why do you need to use `datetime.time` but not `pd.Timedelta`?

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang. I am reading an Excel file that has a column with times. Do you suggest another method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. A [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) cannot be reduced to just `time` only without losing the required datatype for resampling on time window.
2. [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) counts the non-NaN values in a column so one must be provided since there are no remaining columns in the sample frame.

We can fix the first issue by turning the time column into a datetime:

```
timeIntervals = pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min") # remove time here
df = pd.DataFrame({"Times": timeIntervals})
```

If we are not creating these values from a `date_range` we can simply convert the column [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Then we can groupby and count:

```
value = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Times", freq="3H"))['Times'].count()
```

If needed we can update the `index` to only reflect the `time` after grouping:

```
value.index = value.index.time
```

As a result `value` becomes:

```
09:00:00    2
12:00:00    6
15:00:00    6
18:00:00    6
21:00:00    2
Name: Times, dtype: int64
```

---

All together with `to_datetime`:

```
def main():
    time_intervals = pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min").time
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Times": time_intervals})
    # Convert to DateTime
    df['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'], format='%H:%M:%S')
    # Group and count specific column
    value = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Times", freq="3H"))['Times'].count()
    # Retrieve only Time information
    value.index = value.index.time
    print(value)
```

Or without retrieving `time` before DataFrame creation:

```
def main():
    time_intervals = pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min")
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Times": time_intervals})
    value = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Times", freq="3H"))['Times'].count()
    value.index = value.index.time
    print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you think it is possible without modifying column "Times" ?

Comment: You cannot use grouper unless it is a valid time-like type.

Comment: Good. So, an array of datetime.time objects is not a valid time-like type ? I am still struggling to see the difference between datetime, datetime.time and DateIndex.

Comment: datetime.time is object. It has to be a valid dtype to work either `datetime64[ns]` or `timedelta64[ns]` which are both numeric representations of time (in nanoseconds). The resampling operations are math based. This cannot be done with the word `'00:00:01'` but it can be done with the number `1000000000`